# Using JAVA API update Rally Team membership

Tags: json, rally, arrays, java

My Java API compares Team members from another application with Rally. The compared results is updated in Rally. It takes the reference of Project name and Res name.

The code throws "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" error. I coudn't spot the error. Could some one help? Following is the code and the output

```
    package teammembership;

    import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
    import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
    import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
    import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
    import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
    import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
    import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
    import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import org.apache.soap.util.xml.*;
    import org.w3c.dom.*;
    //import org.json.*;
    //import static projectteammembers.JsonUtil.getJsonValue;

    public class TeamMembership {

        public static Connection makeConnection(String propertiesFile) throws SQLException, Exception {

    Connection conn = null;

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = XMLParserUtils.getXMLDocBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(propertiesFile));

    // Retrieve database parameters
    Element database = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("database").item(0);
    String url = database.getAttribute("url");
    String serviceId = database.getAttribute("serviceId");
    String username = database.getAttribute("username");
    String password = database.getAttribute("password");
    String host = url.substring(url.indexOf("//"), url.indexOf(";"));
    String connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + "/" + serviceId;

    // Load JDBC Driver
    String driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    Class.forName(driverClass);

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, username, password);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new SQLException(ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }

    return conn;

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, SQLException {

    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
    String username = "username@abc.com";
    String password = "password";
    //String userRef = "";
    String applicationName = "update team membership";
    //int queryLimit = 4000;
    Connection conn = null;
    String propertiesFile = "";
    propertiesFile = "c:/app/c/properties_prod.xml";
    String projid = "";
    String resid = "";
    //String returnValue = "";
    String selectString = "";

    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
        new URI(host),
        username,
        password);
    restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
    System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion());

    try {

        conn = makeConnection(propertiesFile);


        // Select compared records of Team member present in table1 not in table2
        selectString += "select Prj_name ";
        selectString += ",res_name";
        selectString += " from CUST_table1_v c ";
        selectString += " WHERE NOT EXISTS( select 1 from CUST_table2_v r";
        selectString += " where c.prj_name = r.Prj_name and c.res_name = r.res_name)";

        // Create select statement

        Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        // Execute select statement

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(selectString);

        while (rs.next()) {

            projid = rs.getString("Prj_name");
            resid = "(" + rs.getString("res_name") + ")";


            System.out.println(projid);
            System.out.println(resid);

            QueryRequest projectRequest = new QueryRequest("Project");
            projectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
            projectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", projid));
            QueryResponse projectQueryResponse = restApi.query(projectRequest);
            JsonObject projectObj = projectQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

            QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
            userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserPermissions", "TeamMemberships"));
            userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("DisplayName", "contains", resid));
            QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
            System.out.println(userQueryResponse);
            JsonObject userObject = userQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            //JsonObject projectObj = new JsonObject(projid);
            String userRef = userObject.get("_ref").toString();
            System.out.println("Found User with Ref: " + userRef);

            JsonArray existTeamMemberships = (JsonArray) userQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("TeamMemberships");

            // add or remove projects for user
            existTeamMemberships.add(projectObj);

            // Setup update fields/values for Team Membership
            JsonObject updateUserTeamMembershipObj = new JsonObject();
            updateUserTeamMembershipObj.add("TeamMemberships", existTeamMemberships);

            UpdateRequest updateTeamMembershipsRequest = new UpdateRequest(userRef, updateUserTeamMembershipObj);
            UpdateResponse updateTeamMembershipResponse = restApi.update(updateTeamMembershipsRequest);


        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        restApi.close();
        conn.close();
    }

}
```

}

Following is the error out put

```
    v2.0
    DT-E2E Automation
    (tmanjunath)

    com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse@193d23b
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.google.gson.JsonArray.get(JsonArray.java:92)
        at teammembership.TeamMembership.main(TeamMembership.java:125)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a List (an ArrayList to be exact) which contains nothing (no single object) and you try to access the first object (which doesn't exist). That's what the error tells you. You try to access index 0 (the first position in the list) but there is no element in it (so the size is 0). It happens around line 125. Since your formatting in the question doesn't seem to be correct, I can only guess which line in your question is line 125 (and I don't want to read 125 lines of code by the way). So I think the exception occurs here:

```
JsonObject userObject = userQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
```

Try to track it down. Make sure the list returned from `userQueryResponse.getResults()` contains something:

```
list = userQueryResponse.getResults();
System.out.println(list.size());
```

If not, that's your problem. If you cannot solve it, ask a specific question about this problem without posting 150 line of code.

Comment: Sorry for spamming with the whole code. I'm new to Java & Rally. I'm trying to update the team membership using Java API. As you said it didn't provide any value. So I updated the code to avoid IndexOutofBound Exception. Actually I found this part of code in this forum and used it. Now it shows the NullPointer exception where it updates the team membership. That would be  in `existTeamMemberships.add(projectObj);`. I checked userref, it gives the user details. The user is not member of any project. So I'm trying to add him to the project.  If I'm not clear, please forgive me.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question? If you get a NullPointerException in the line `existTeamMemberships.add(projectObj);` I guess the variable `existTeamMemberships` is null (instead of a list).

Comment: I've already updated the code. Thanks. I was trying to Add team members to the project, even if that team member is not associated with any other project. Since in this case, my team member was not associated with any project. So looking for the code which could help me to add team members to the project

Comment: Mmm.. OK, so your team member is in no project yet and therefore `existTeamMemberships` is null and doesn't exist. Am I right? You request the memberships, there are none and you get null. Can you just  create a JSON array (e.g. new `JSONArray()` or so), add your member and pass it to `updateUserTeamMembershipObj.add(...);`?

Answer (score 0):

`get("_ref").toString()` used to work with the older versions, and the code you refer to is older. When using 2.0.4 jar (which by default uses the most recent version of WS API  in production, v2.0) replace all instances of it with `get("_ref").getAsString()`.

For example,

```
String userRef = userObject.get("_ref").toString();
```

will generate java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null

Comment: Thanks Nick. But error is not in that line. I'm trying to make the user (who is already the editor to the project) as Team member to the project. I got the team member name and the Project name.  `JsonArray existTeamMemberships = (JsonArray) userQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("TeamMemberships"); 
existTeamMemberships.add(projectObj);` has the error when trying to provide Team membership for the project. Could you please help?